# Using an Italian Windows keyboard in remote management of iMac

Tags: keyboard, windows, remote-desktop

I'm using TeamViewer on a Windows computer to control an iMac. The keyboard on my side is [this](http://i1041.photobucket.com/albums/b412/digitalstore20100/TRTERTW/KEY-615_001_zpsf9f820fa.jpg), but I set it so that it works like [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Apple_iMac_Keyboard_A1243.png) (when I push <kbd>\</kbd> I obtain `, when I push <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> I get ~, and so on).

At the beginning I thought it was unavoidable, so I started to get used to these changes (hard to do, since I write in LaTeX and the backslash is the most important non alphabetical character). Accidentally I changed the settings such that the keyboard is mapped in the right way, but I don't know how. So far, it's fine; then I unfortunately (and accidentally) turned things back, so I think it's the moment to understand how to manage this settings.

In System Preferences > Keyboard I see there's only the Italian keyboard. Furthermore, even if I add and select other keyboards, I always get ~ when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> (the original behavior).

Could the problem concern being connected remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not a problem concerning TeamViewer, nor the preferences/settings of the Mac. Evidently I accidentally pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>, thus changing the keyboard input method in Windows from Ita to Eng. I realized this by simply visualizing the keyboard on screen and watching it change depending on which window was active.